# UniqueValueRenderer will not write polygons to the map

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, symbology, cartographic-information-model

I'm attempting to apply symbology to a polygons layer. It does set symbology to the layer, but the actual info is stuck in .

What is wrong in my code?

```py
T = "19N"
R = "5E"
TWP = "T"+T+"_"+"R"+R

import arcpy, sys, os, datetime
print(TWP)

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
l = m.listLayers(TWP + "_RIGHTS")[0]
sym = l.symbology

sym.updateRenderer('UniqueValueRenderer')
sym.renderer.fields = ['RightsType']

for grp in sym.renderer.groups:
  for itm in grp.items:
    label = itm.label

    if itm.label == "Choose":
        itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [0, 0, 0, 50]}      
        itm.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [255, 255, 255, 100]}
        itm.symbol.outlineWidth = 0.75
        itm.label = str(label)

    if itm.label == "Easement":
        itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [0, 112, 255, 50]}      
        itm.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [255, 255, 255, 100]}
        itm.symbol.outlineWidth = 0.75  
        itm.label = str(label)

    if itm.label == "Fee":
        itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [56, 168, 0, 50]}
        itm.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [255, 255, 255, 100]}
        itm.symbol.outlineWidth = 0.75
        itm.label = str(label)

    if itm.label == "License":
        itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [255, 0, 0, 50]}
        itm.symbol.outlineColor = {"RGB": [255, 255, 255, 100]}
        itm.symbol.outlineWidth = 0.75
        itm.label = str(label)

    print(label)
        
    l.symbology = sym

aprx.save() 
print("Completed"+" "+time.strftime("%x" +" "+ "(%a)" +" "+ "at"+" "+"%I:%M"))
```

Comment: The TWP + "_RIGHTS" layer use domains, I'm thinking now that is the source of the problem

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information that may be relevant to it.